# Save image to device

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi i cant seem to get his code to work

```
    //Save Image To Device
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.ImageURLS objectAtIndex:0]]]];
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"saving jpg");
NSString *jpgFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpg",docDir,[self.NameArray objectAtIndex:0]];
NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];//1.0f = 100% quality
[data2 writeToFile:jpgFilePath atomically:YES];
```

and i am getting the image via

```
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *jpgFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpg",docDir,[self.NameArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:jpgFilePath];
```

Any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last line of your code to

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:jpgFilePath];
```

UIImage's `+imageNamed:` searches the app bundle for a file with a given name, which is not what you need.

Comment: i think its something to do with the save tbh

Comment: Where does your code give incorrect/unexpected results? Can you step through it with a debugger, looking at the values returned at each step?

Comment: no were its all 0 warnings etc i just have enver had to save a image before so i dont really have a clue with it

Comment: OK, check the value returned by `[NSURL URLWithString:[self.ImageURLS objectAtIndex:0]]`, it looks most suspicious to me. Also it seems strange that you save the image with the name at index 0: [self.NameArray objectAtIndex:0], and then read this: [self.NameArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]. Is [indexPath row] zero?

Comment: What about image file name (see the previous comment)?